# How can I reference an object inside one of its member functions?

Tags: javascript, oop, this

I have the following:

```
var o = {f: function(fn) {
    fn.call(o);
}};
var ob = {f: function() {
    o.f(function() {
        this.x = 2; //HERE: how can this reference ob?
        //ob.x = 2;
    });
}};
ob.f();
ob.x; // undefined
```

`o.f(fn)` calls `fn` where `this` is bound to o.

At HERE, I want to use `this` to access ob.
However, when `ob.f` is called, `this` is bound to `o`.
JQuery works like this, I think.
For example:

```
$(...).blah(function() {
    this // this is bound to $(...) jquery object.
    ...
};
```

What I'm doing now is:

```
var Ob = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.f = function() {
        o.f(function() { self.x = 2; };
    };
};
var ob = new Ob();
ob.f();
ob.x; // 2
```

But I don't like above for stylistic reasons:

1. Using the `new` operator sounds like too classical OOP.
2. Defining `class Ob` using `function` isn't intuitive (at least in the beginning).

That's why I am trying to define `ob` with an object literal.
But I can't find a way to reference the object `ob` in a function
that uses method call that sets `this` to other object than `ob`.

I can do something like the following:

```
var ob = {f: function() {
    o.f(function() {
        self.x = 2;
    });
}};
var self = ob;
ob.f();
ob.x;
```

But I don't know how to factor above.
I tried:

```
function obj(o) {
    return function() {
        var self = o;
        return o;
    }();
}
var ob = obj({f: function() {
    o.f(function() {
        self.x = 2;
    });
}});
ob.f();
ob.x;// ReferenceError: self is not defined
```

So, is there a way to reference the object in a function inside the object
reliably (`this` can bound to anything depending on the context)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Douglas Crockfords simple constructor pattern, I would make a constructor-function that uses the object literal instead of new. Like this:

```
var o = {f: function(fn) {
    fn.call(o);
}};

function obj() {
    var me = {};
    me.f = function () {
        o.f(function() {
            me.x = 2;
        });
    };
    return me;
}

var ob = obj();
ob.f();
ob.x; // 2
```

Comment: 'self' is already a global variable, like 'undefined' and 'NaN'. Please use another name to make it less confusing.

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, functions are objects, having two methods to invoke the function:

```
call(scope, arg1, arg2, ...);
apply(scope, args);  // args is an array of arguments to call the function with
```

The first argument, 'scope', is the object that is bound to 'this' within the function. So, the following examples are equivalent:

```
obj.method(1, 2, 3);
obj.method.call(obj, 1, 2, 3);
obj.method.apply(obj, [1, 2, 3]);
```

In your first example, you are calling the function passed to o.f() using 'o' as scope:

```
var o = {f: function(fn) {
    fn.call(o);
}};
```

Therefore your function passed in 'ob' references 'o' as this:

```
var ob = {f: function() {
    o.f(function() {
        this.x = 2; //HERE: how can this reference ob?
        //ob.x = 2;
    });
}};
```

In the line 'HERE', 'this' is actually 'o'.

You could try the following:

```
var ob = {f: function() {
    var self = this;
    o.f(function() {
        self.x = 2; // self is ob now
    });
}};
```

Or you could modify the function 'o.f' to take a scope parameter:

```
var o = {f: function(fn, scope) {
    fn.call(scope || this); // Uses the given scope or this (= 'o') if no scope is provided
}};
```

Then you can pass 'this' in 'ob':

```
var ob = {f: function() {
    o.f(function() {
        this.x = 2; // 'this' will be the 'outer' this
    }, this); // Here: this as scope
}};
```

Comment: I was trying to simulate behavior of jquery object with o.  As I noted in jquery, **this** is set to jquery object itself even when the function is being defined inside my object. I like Douglas Crockfords simple constructor pattern posted by Magnar.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without auxiliary functions, just using literals:

```
var o = {f: function(fn) {
    fn.call(o);
}};
var ob = {f: function() {
    var self = this; // this == ob
    o.f(function() {
        self.x = 2; // self == enclosing function's this == ob
    });
}};
ob.f();
assert(ob.x == 2);
```